# Is Lucene .NET Dead?

Tags: lucene.net

http://lucene.apache.org/lucene.net/ is 404'ing and it's nowhere to be found on the incubator SVN at https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator.

What gives?

Comment: Allow me to be more precise - is Lucene.NET dead to Apache?  It had a nice dedicated homepage not long ago, not just the dry incubator page.  That it isn't under incubator SVN anymore is discouraging.

Comment: Lucene.net is no longer in the Incubator. It seems that the new address is http://lucenenet.apache.org/.

Comment: thank you!  google searching this was leading me nowhere

Comment: Amazing how hard it was to find this.